# Conversion of mass into energy with 100% efficiency

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy, antimatter

Suppose you are given a mass of 1 kg. Einstein's theory of relativity says that all the mass can be converted into energy as per the equation $E = mc^2$.

So if you want to convert this whole mass of 1 kg into energy, what will you do to that mass?

Comment: Converted to photons: ie. light and heat (BANG!)

Comment: with anti-matter?

Answer (score 32):

Although pop sci sources often phrase it in terms of “converting” mass into energy, it is incorrect. $E=mc^2$ says that if you have a stationary mass $m$ then it already has an amount of energy $E=mc^2$. No conversion is necessary. The energy is already there otherwise energy would not be conserved. Also, an amount of stationary energy $E$ has a mass $m=E/c^2$, again no conversion necessary.

What you can do is to convert matter at rest with total mass $m$ into photons with total energy $E=mc^2$. In principle you could do that by using antimatter, so if your mass consisted of 0.5 kg of electrons and 0.5 kg of positrons then it would work.

Comment: Or a black hole, although you might need to be prepared to wait a while.

Comment: at least your black hole isn't as efficient as OP claims .. the top rate observed and calculated is about 42...43% . the remaining mass "falls into" the black hole

Comment: @eagle275 You scoop up the remaining mass as Hawking radiation and repeat the process. That's where the waiting a while bit comes into play.

Comment: @eagle275 - I think what is meant is the black hole evaporation by Hawking radiation: note the comment "might need to be prepared to wait a while" :)

Comment: At a guess, matter–antimatter annihilation isn’t “100% efficient”—my impression is that nothing ever is—and that seems worth addressing in the answer? I suppose that inefficiency may come into play more when you try to *do something* with the energy released, as opposed to the “conversion” since energy is conserved, but nonetheless I for one would be interested in seeing at least a little bit of exposition on “efficiency” here.

Comment: I suspect efficiency is not well defined unless you're using the energy to do something; conventional definitions of efficiency are the amount of useful work vs waste energy. If you just annihilate a bunch of matter and anti-matter in a vacuum, it's by definition 0% efficient, since you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: @KRyan it depends what you mean by efficiency in this case. It is not a thermodynamic cycle, so the usual definitions and restrictions don’t apply. If efficiency is simply energy in over energy out, then that is 100% efficient. If efficiency is energy in over photon energy out then efficiency will be more like 99.99% efficient as about 1/10000 will decay to neutrinos instead of photons. If efficiency is energy in over work out, then that would depend on how you extract work from the photons.

Comment: If we assume for the sake of the argument that "energy" here means "electromagnetic radiation" with rest mass 0 as opposed to other particles with a finite rest mass then the efficiency is < 100% because annihilation of composite particles like (anti)protons is complex and [creates a zoo of particle pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Proton-antiproton_annihilation which then decay, partially ending up as electrons and positrons.

Comment: That is why I suggested 0.5 kg of electrons and 0.5 kg of positrons. Those decay almost (99.99%) exclusively to photons. Protons and anti-protons are messy.

Comment: You'll probably also "lose" energy to gravity waves. I suppose that'll be minute, but it still cuts away from the 100%...

Comment: @JoãoMendes if gravity waves are not energy then I don't know what is ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I meant that it's also not "electromagnetic radiation". ;p

Comment: @Dale, is there a reason you picked 99.99% or are you just saying it's a high number? Can you say it's definitely above 80% and below 99.999999%?

Comment: Even electrons and positrons are tricky in regard to converting them into photons. Sometimes they produce neutrinos instead.

Comment: @Jetpack according to Wikipedia it is about 1 decay in every 10000 that produce neutrinos. So 99.99% produce photons. I.e. I am not just saying a random big number, that is the best estimate I have of the true fraction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation

Comment: Actually, a 1Kg black hole would have a temperature of about $10^{23}K$ and would evaporate in $10^{-18}s$. So you wouldn't have to wait very long at all.

Comment: How does the black hole method (or any other method that doesn't use equal amounts of matter and anti-matter) square with baryon conservation? Surely you're always left with rest mass?

Comment: With the electron-position method (0.5 kg of each) the efficiency would be less that what is presented here because some of the particles will miss eachother in any real experiment. (I mean, what are the chances that every single one of your $10^{23}$ or so electrons finds one of the positrons perfectly and no leftover particles are left floating about or get pushed away into the distant universe by the huge photon explosion you just produced with the ones that did annihilate.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to convert a kg of matter to other forms of energy is to bring along a 1 kg mass of antimatter and have them annihilate. However I have always felt that this is a bad method, because it is well known that antimatter is very rare, and very difficult to produce. So as an answer it merely shifts the problem into "how do I obtain or manufacture 1 kg of anti-matter?" Most methods to make antimatter will be very inefficient in practice.

So I prefer the much cleaner gravitational methods. The following is a beautiful piece of gravitational physics which deserves to be more widely known.

We dangle a mass using a massless string. According to General Relativity, for a static source, if you stand at $B$ and lower an object to $A$ using a massless string, then the energy extracted at $B$ is given by
$$
W = \left( 1 - \frac{e^{\Phi(A)/c^2}}{e^{\Phi(B)/c^2}}
\right) E_B
$$
where $\Phi$ is gravitational potential and $E_B$ is the energy the object has when at $B$. For someone at $B$ this would be the rest energy of the object.

Now we take $B$ to be at infinity, and use the Schwarzschild metric. Then $\Phi(r) = (1/2) c^2 \ln(1 - r_s / r)$ and we find
$$
W = \left( 1 - \sqrt{1 - r_s/r} \right) m_0 c^2.
$$
To repeat, this is the energy (work) gathered at $B$ when someone stands there lowering the object using a massless string. Now lower the object all the way to the event horizon of a black hole: the place where $r = r_s$. In that case $W = m_0 c^2$. The entire rest energy of the object has been seamlessly and smoothly converted into work. The string then breaks and the lowered object enters the black hole. And here's the kicker: the mass of the black hole does not then change! The black hole doesn't get any of the rest energy of the lowered object; it all stays at $B$.

So that is how I would convert a kg with 100% efficiency.

Processes somewhat like this one occur in the accretion discs (i.e. orbiting material) around black holes, and the energy goes to the form of kinetic energy of the material in the disc. In other words, the disc gets very hot. There is no 'string' of course, but the collisions as matter slowly falls on a spiral orbit perform the function of such a string.

Finally, a thought which follows from the above. For any given object, including all the ordinary objects sitting around you as you read this, their rest energy can be regarded as the energy that would have had to be provided to raise them from the horizon of a black hole to the place where they are now located.

Answer (score 0):

This is an equation that only tells half the story - For a more full picture of the energy we should use the equation;
$$ E= mc^2 + \hbar \lambda  $$

For anything with mass; the last term can be approximated to 0.
For anything without mass, the first term is 0.

This means that should you take some mass; and turn it into "not mass"; that energy must be converted into the last term - that last term is the energy of light..

This is how power stations etc work; (from a 10,000ft view) they're able to convert a small percentage of the fuel into light; and that light is then absorbed by water which heats up and turns to steam.

Comment: (1) Your equation is wrong. You can use $E = \sqrt{m^2 c^4 + p^2 c^2}$ if you like, but $E=m c^2$ remains correct as a statement about rest energy, which is precisely what it is. (2) Power stations don't convert fuel into light, they convert the energy stored in molecular bonds into kinetic energy of molecules.

Comment: @AndrewSteane sorry - should've said "nuclear" power stations.  my mind was thinking what my fingers weren't typeing

Comment: OK; for nuclear power stations they convert the nuclear stored energy mainly into kinetic energy of neutrons and kinetic energy of the product nuclei; only a little goes to gamma rays I think.